# Old Domain 301 Redirect to New Domain with HTAccess Wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a old domain lets call it

```
example.com
```

I want to do a 301 redirect of all its page and its homepage to

```
newsite.com
```

So for example

```
example.com/category/page.html
```

Should 301 redirect to

```
newsite.com/category/page.html
```

And also

```
example.com should redirect to newsite.com
```

Be it with **www or without www**

I tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.tv/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

My folder structure is

```
index.html
.htaccess
```

When I go in the site, be it with wildcard or not, it only load the index.html and the .htaccess redirect is not working.

I did enable **modrewrite**

Can anyone guide me to set up the right .htaccess for this case.

Thanks!

Comment: Your comment 'When I go in the site, be it with wildcard or not, it only load the index.html' is not entirely clear. Could you clarify which URL you are typing into the browser and on which of the two sites the `index.html` file is loading? Do you get redirected to `newsite.com` at all or are you staying on `example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use RedirectMatch directive .

Try this in Olddomain/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1
```